# Theming Using Bootstrap Glyphicons and WordPress Dashicons

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, html, icon

I use a mixture of both *Bootstrap Glyphicons* and *WordPress Dashicons* in my *WordPress themes*.

However, something which really bugs me is how the WordPress Dashicons don't seem to scale appropriately with different HTML elements (more specifically, variances of font sizes).

If you have a Heading 1 for example...

---

### Bootstrap Glyphicons

**Programmatically looks like:**

`<h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> Gallery</h1>`

**Visually looks like:**

[image: Bootstrap Glyphicon]

---

### WordPress Dashicons

**Programmatically looks like:**

`<h1><span class="dashicons dashicons-portfolio"></span> Gallery</h1>`

**Visually looks like:**

[image: WordPress Dashicon]

---

Why do the WordPress Dashicons not scale properly? I'd like to be able to use a mixture of both **WordPress Dashicons** and **Bootstrap Glyphicons** in my **WordPress themes**, but it gets really annoying having to always adjust the WordPress Dashicons manually for EACH icon used, to make it scale appropriately with each element, and media query.

Is there a global CSS fix which can be applied to ALL WordPress Dashicons, so that they behave like the Bootstrap Glyphicons, without screwing up other areas in WordPress which use the WordPress Dashicons?

Comment: Were are you trying to use them? I thought that as the name entails, Dashicons are meant to be used in the Dashboard for custom icons in the navigation. As such, they are sized to fit the space and font size of the dashboard menu items.

Comment: Well, WordPress Dashicons are essentially a "Glyphicon", right? I'm using them in my WordPress themes. So AKA the frontend. Bootstrap's Glyphicons do a fantastic job at scaling, no matter what the font size is. I just feel like there's some kind of CSS tweak to enable WordPress's Dashicons to behave the same as Bootstrap's Glyphicons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at Bootstrap's Glyphicon `CSS` and WordPress's Dashicon `CSS` and formulated a tweak.

### Bootstrap Glyphicons `CSS`

```
.glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

### WordPress Dashicons `CSS`

```
.dashicons {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: dashicons;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
    transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

### WordPress Dashicons `CSS` (Tweaked)

```
body .dashicons {
    font-size: inherit !important;
    height: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
    text-align: inherit !important;
    top: 1px !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Be cautious when adding the **Tweaked WordPress Dashicons `CSS`** to your website. You may want to use a hook and just print it ([`wp_print_styles`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles)), or you could make a specific `CSS` file and enqueue it ([`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)). Either way, which ever route you decide to take, make sure the `CSS` tweak is only applied to the frontend.

I'm pretty sure it's safe to use in the backend, but I only needed to make these adjustments on the frontend, so why bother screwing with something that works fine for WordPress in the backend?

If you decide to use this `CSS` tweak in one of your WordPress plugins, just make sure that you're only printing it or enqueuing it on pages used by your plugin, and not globally across the entire backend.

Anywhoo, there you have it. Solved my own question. Hope this helps someone else.

**Side note:**

Some areas using the WordPress Dashicons require a space after and some don't. However, 90% of the time the Bootstrap Glyphicons look fine always having a space after them. I think it just depends on the size of the font the icon is scaling to. It's situational I guess. Just keep an eye out for that.

Once again... Visually...

**Bootstrap Glyphicon**

[image: Bootstrap Glyphicon]

**WordPress Dashicon (Not using tweaked `CSS`)**

[image: WordPress Dashicon (Not using tweaked CSS)]

**WordPress Dashicon (Using tweaked `CSS`)**

[image: WordPress Dashicon (Using tweaked CSS)]

**P.S.** WordPress Dashicons are only available to use while the user is logged in. If you'd like to use WordPress Dashicons in your WordPress theme if the user is NOT logged in, you need to enqueue it. **Like this:** `wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use em sizing to make the dashicons scale relative to the font size of their containing element. This should do the trick:

```
.dashicons:before {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Then if your `<h1>` element has a font-size of `48px`, your dashicon will as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wp_add_inline_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) to attach some css to dashicon style.

Using that function everytime you add dashicons css via `wp_enqueue_script` you can automatically append some css and so modify default styles.

Something like:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_add_inline_style(
        'dashicons',
        '.dashicons { font-size:inherit; line-height:inherit; display:inline-table; }'
    );
}, 999);
```

What css to put inside the function is off-topic here, but the example given above should be a good starting point.

Note that `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` is not fired in backend, so the code will not affect your admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, the dashicons are meant to be part of the dashboard menu, as such they are sized very specifically:

```
.dashicons-before:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: dashicons;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
    transition: color .1s ease-in 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Notice the width, height, and font-size. If I were you, I'd make my own class, that uses the same font-family, but user glyphicon classes to size them:

.my-dashicon { font-family: dashicons !important; }

Then use like this:

```
<h1><span class="glyphicons my-dashicos dashicons-portfolio"></span> Gallery</h1>
```

I can't test my code above, so it may not work, but maybe it gives you an idea on where to start.